# How do I know what to put in the XML fields?

Tags: xml

So, I recently posted a question regarding a similar topic, but I feel that it was too broad.  I'm just now hoping for someone to help me understand what to put in my XML, and wether I am doing this correctly.  This is my first time working with XML, so please forgive me if this question is trivial.

[Based on this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee652282(v=vs.100).aspx), I am trying to create an XML to send to my Identity Management tool to create a group.  However, I am having a hard time understanding the examples given on the site.  This is what they have:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:da="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/11/IdentityManagement/DirectoryAccess" 
xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
```

For `xmlns:da="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/11/IdentityManagement/DirectoryAccess"`, would I put my target location there, or is this namespace declaration for a pre-defined schema that I should include, like the w3 declarations?  Then there is `<wsa:To s:mustUnderstand="1"> http://localhost:5725/ResourceManagementService/ResourceFactory</wsa:To>`  I assume the To is my target URL for the FIM tool.  If anyone could help with this, I would greatly appreciate this.  I cannot find much out there on how to consume the FIM tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is just the root of a SOAP envelope that is defining the name space prefixes.
And yes the `xmlns:da="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/11/IdentityManagement/DirectoryAccess"` is just defining the namespace prefix da which is then used later on e.g. `<da:IdentityManagementOperation s:mustUnderstand="1" />`

Yes to `<wsa:to ..` is your target URL for FIM.

There is a link from the page you gave that goes to [WS-Transfer: Identity Management Operations for Directory Access Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd302851.aspx) which has a link to a PDF file to download.  That goes into great details and gives examples of how to use it.

The full message from the page for reference, minus the invalid repeat.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:da="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/11/IdentityManagement/DirectoryAccess" 
xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"> 
    <s:Header> 
        <wsa:Action 
s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Create</wsa:Action> 
        <da:IdentityManagementOperation s:mustUnderstand="1" /> 
        <wsa:ReplyTo> 
<wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address> 
        </wsa:ReplyTo> 
        <wsa:To 
s:mustUnderstand="1">http://localhost:5725/ResourceManagementService/ResourceFactory</wsa:To>    
</s:Header> 
    <s:Body> 
        <da:AddRequest 
Dialect="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/11/ResourceManagement/Dialect/IdentityAttributeTyp
e-20080602"> 
            <da:AttributeTypeAndValue> 
                <da:AttributeType>ObjectType</da:AttributeType> 
                <da:AttributeValue> 
                    <rm:ObjectType>ma-data</rm:ObjectType> 
                </da:AttributeValue> 
            </da:AttributeTypeAndValue> 
            <da:AttributeTypeAndValue> 
                <da:AttributeType>DisplayName</da:AttributeType> 
                <da:AttributeValue> 
                    <rm:DisplayName> 
                      Active Directory Management Agent 
                    </rm:DisplayName> 
                </da:AttributeValue> 
            </da:AttributeTypeAndValue> 
        </da:AddRequest> 
    </s:Body> 
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a respose!  I've been getting pretty desperate finding an answer, haha.  I just have a few more questions if you don't mind.  I want to create a new group, and the URL for groups is `http://my.target.url.com/IdentityManagament/Groups`.  Would that be my target URL, or would I just hit `http://my.target.url.com`?  Secondly, in the example, it repeats the XML a second time.  I thought it was a bug, but is it necessary to have it twice?  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: The repeat after the </s:Envelope> is an issue with that page, that is not correct.

Comment: You have a typo in IdentityManagement (you have an a after the g instead of a e).  The example they give has  `net.tcp://server01.fabrikam.com:9389/ActiveDirectoryWebServices/Windows/ResourceFactory`. It is what is in the Body that determines the type of the request e..g AddRequest, ModifyRequest & BaseObjectSearchRequest that have the URL for the action

Comment: There is a WSDL in the PDF.  Consume that in whatever solution you are building.

Comment: Yeah, reading through that at the moment (can't believe I missed that, I've been on that site before).  I guess what my problem is (I keep getting 401 http responses, thought my XML was bad) that I don't have the full path to the ResourceFactory.  Just need to modify that when I figure out what it is :)